# What is the difference between a constant and a variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

So, I'm doing a Ruby course on CodeAcademy and I'm stuck in differentiating the difference between a variable and a class. Can someone please explain the difference to me? I'll give you cookies! ^^. No matter where I look online I can't find any information on this.

Comment: Are you asking about a `constant` as in the question title or `class` as in the question body?

Answer (score 4):

The idea of constants in Ruby is that they can get a value assigned only once while you can assign a new value to a variable as many times as you want. Now technically, you can assign a new value even to a constant. Ruby will however issue a warning in this case and you should try to avoid this case.

I guess the main point leading to confusion of people new to Ruby is that even values assigned to constants can be modified without a warning (e.g. by adding new elements to an array). References by a constant are no different to variables here in that the reference does not restrict what can be done with the value. The object referenced by either a variable or constant is always independent from that.

In this example, I assign a new array to the `ARRAY` constant. Later, I can happily change the array by adding a new member to it. The constant is not concerned by this.

```
ARRAY = []
# => []
ARRAY << :foo
ARRAY
# => [:foo]
```

The only thing forbidden (or, well, allowed with a warning) is if you try to assign a completely new value to a constant:

```
ARRAY2 = []
# => []
ARRAY2 = [:bar]
# warning: already initialized constant ARRAY2
ARRAY2
=> [:bar]
```

As such, it is common practice to immediately freeze values assigned to constants to fully deny any further changes and ensure that the original value is preserved (unless someone assigns a new value):

```
ARRAY3 = [:foo, :bar].freeze
ARRAY3 << :baz
# RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array
```

Comment: In your first example, you are *not* changing the constant. You are changing the object referenced by the constant. This is only a point of confusion if you don't understand the difference between a thing and a name used to refer to a thing. But if you don't understand that difference, then there will be whole lot of other things that confuse you, anyway.

Comment: @JörgWMittag This is exactly what I was trying to say, albeit probably a bit too brief. I edited my answer to clarify this a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

- A variable can change its value, it can vary.
- A constant cannot change its value, it is constant.

In Ruby things are a bit more complex though. You can reassign the value of constants, but it will print a warning. This is meant to be used for debugging only and the general principle still applies that constants are meant to be used for values that never change.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, a constant is an identifier that starts with a capital letter; it is intended to be assigned only once.  You can reassign a constant, but you should not.  Doing so will generate a warning:

```
NAME = "Fred"
NAME = "Barney"    # => Warning: Already initialized constant NAME
```

A variable is an identifier that does not start with a capital letter; it may be assigned to more than once:

```
name = "Fred"
name = "Barney"    # => No warning
```

When you create a class, a constant is created with the same name as the class; that constant is bound to the class:

```
class Foo
end
```

This is equivalent to this code which creates a new anonymous class and assigns it to the constant Foo:

```
Foo = Class.new do
end
```

You can reassign the constant identifier Foo, as you can with any other constant, but of course you shouldn't, and you will still get the warning:

```
Foo = 123    # => Already initialized constant Foo
```