# "Already initialized constant" warning

Tags: ruby

Here's my code:

```
puts "Input a number."
Divisor = 2
inputNumber = gets.chomp
if inputNumber.to_i == 1 || inputNumber.to_i == 2
  if inputNumber.to_i == 1
    puts inputNumber + " is not a prime."
  else
    puts inputNumber + " is a prime."
  end
else
  while Divisor.to_i < inputNumber.to_i
    if inputNumber.to_i%Divisor.to_i == 0
      puts inputNumber + " is not a Prime as " + Divisor.to_s + " is a factor."
      break
    else 
      Divisor = Divisor.to_i + 1
    end
  end
  puts inputNumber + " is a prime!"
end
```

I got the following error:

```
test1.rb:30: warning: already initialized constant Divisor
test1.rb:3: warning: previous definition of Divisor was here
```

What is wrong?

Comment: That's not error, that's a warning. (It clearly says so: "warning".)

Answer (score 5):

## Constants and variables

`Divisor` is a constant. You want a variable : `divisor`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272255/what-is-the-difference-between-a-constant-and-a-variable-in-ruby).

## Notes

- `puts inputNumber + " is a prime!"` is always called.
- You could replace `break` by `exit`, or use a boolean variable.
- Since you work with numbers, you could also call `.to_i` once, do your calculation, and just use `.to_s` to display results
- You only have to check for factors in the range `(2..Math.sqrt(inputNumber))`
- You don't have to check twice if `inputNumber == 1`

---

```
puts 'Input a number.'
divisor = 2
inputNumber = gets.chomp.to_i
prime = true
if inputNumber == 1
  puts inputNumber.to_s + ' is not a prime.'
else
  while divisor <= Math.sqrt(inputNumber)
    if inputNumber % divisor == 0
      puts inputNumber.to_s + ' is not a Prime as ' + divisor.to_s + ' is a factor.'
      prime = false
      break
    else
      divisor += 1
    end
  end
  puts inputNumber.to_s + ' is a prime!' if prime
end
```

## Alternative

A shorter alternative can be written with [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find). It executes the block with every element, stops as soon as the code in block returns a truthy value, and returns the element for which the block is truthy. If no element is found, it returns `nil` :

```
puts 'Input a number.'

number = gets.chomp.to_i

divisor = (2..Math.sqrt(number)).find { |i| number % i == 0 }

if number == 1
  puts '1 is not a prime.'
elsif divisor
  puts format('%d is not a prime as %d is a factor.', number, divisor)
else
  puts format('%d is a prime!', number)
end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why this exactly happens? Are `Foo` variables forbidden in Ruby?

Comment: Not much is forbidden in Ruby. You can do it, but you get a warning.

Comment: @Smar there is no `Foo` variable, `Foo` is by definition a constant.

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks for your response! Could you elaborate on the find function in the Alternative? Thanks.

Comment: @StopReadingThisUsername it returns the first number in the given range that satisfies the condition in the block, or `nil` if none is found.

Comment: @Stefan I understand. I had another question, though; when I replaced Divisor with divisor to change the constant to a variable, my code still did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: @StopReadingThisUsername _"my code still did not work"_ – could you be more specific?

Comment: @StopReadingThisUsername: could you explain which part of the documentation of `Enumerable#find` was unclear to you? That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation to help future programmers!

Comment: @JörgWMittag I actually didn't read the documentation. Just thought that an explanation would've been nice with the solution, especially when answering questions for a beginner like me. Thanks for your concern.